# Яким символом позначається українська літера «в» у МФА?

Tags: фонетика

Яким символом варто позначати українську «в» у МФА? Моя думка, що вона позначається як /ʋ/ у звичайній позиції, і як /w/, перед приголосними та наприкінці складів (ў). Виправте мене, якщо я неправий, будь ласка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фонолоґічно¹, що вчать ще ві школї, запис **в** зазвичай розріняють на:

- **в** — передує голосній. Зазвичай цього достатньо, але *декотрі* можуть вказувати також на морфолоґічнну складову, тому якщо **в** є кінцем складу, то стає **ў**. Для прикладу, вимова складової *пів* різна ві словах *півонія* → *півонійа* і *півострів* → *піўостріў*. Також *декотрі* можуть вказувати на одзвінчення **ф**, тобто *Афганістан* → *Авганістан*.
- **ў** — решта випадків.

Фонетичні варіяції. Умовно уставні, тобто переносимо згадане висше сюди:

- **ʋ** — **в**. Поширена думка, що така вимова буває переважно перед переднїми голосними, тобто **і**, рїдше **е** й **и**.
- **u̯** — **ў**.
- Якщо мова про *загальну* українську, то як *декотрі* вказують: **v** — переважно одзвінчена **ф**. Не зовсїм про **в**, так, але згадане висше.

Похідні варіяції:

- **w** — поширена думка, що така вимова зазвичай перед огубленими голосними, тобто **о** й **у**². Також *може* замінювати **u̯** на початку слова перед дзвінкими приголосними як ві *вдова*. А **ʍ** перед глухими приголосними, як ві *вперед*.
- **β** — решта випадків або просто замінник до згаданих **w** чи **ʋ**, тому цей звук часто упускають. А **ɸ**³ — є глухим відповідником, котрий, правда, має дуже рїдку появу, лише в декотрих говірках, тому його зазвичай не згадують.

Є, зьвісно, іще гинші, але то вже не для *загальної* української, а для окремих говорів чи окремої вимови певної особи.

> Наочно: показ декотрих згаданих звуків за допомогою схеми зі статтї [*Адескриптивна прескрипція (про чергування у/в)*](//zbruc.eu/node/41931) Ореста Друля на Збручї.
>
> [image: Схема декотрих варіяцій вимови «в»]

Спробуймо підсумувати, тобто *грубо* перенести згадане на таблицю:

| Вимова | Буква «в» передує |
| --- | --- |
| ʋ | передню голосну |
| w | огублену голосну; дзвінкого приголосного на початку слова |
| ʍ | глухого приголосного на початку слова |
| u̯ | приголосну; початок склада, втч морфолоґічного |
| β | голосну |

Наскільки менї відомо, [лабілізація](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labialization) попереднїх приголосних, насамперед заднїх (нп. *кв*, *хв*), зі втратою самого звука **в** — відсутнє явище в українській. Так, існують записи як *хороба* проти *хвороба*, але тут просто втрата *в* без лабілізації⁴.

---

¹ Вона ж і [фонематична](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97).

² Відповідні «мнякі» йотовані «голосні» також входять сюди, наприклад до **у** — **ю**.

³ Через можливі особливостї шрифтів, зазначу: [не плутати](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bilabial_fricative) з кириличною **ф**.

⁴ Приклад не дуже вдалий, бо лабілізація тут насправді є, але то типова через **о**, тобто не відіграє жодної важливої ролї для мовника. А знайти відповідники через **і** (умовн. приклад: *хвіст* → *хіст*) чи **а** — я не зміг.

Comment: так а яка відповідь на запитання?

Comment: @Yola, наскільки я розумію, можна підсумувати так: при фонологічному (фонематичному) переданні stegetsj радить використовувати **два** символи МФА (на відміну від моєї відповіді, де я кажу про один; які саме — не зазначає, лише кириличні відповідники), а при фонетичному — до **п'яти** (зазначено в таблиці).

Comment: @stegetsj, я, якщо чесно, як і Yola, теж не відразу зрозумів, який висновок. Ваша відповідь однаково добра, але, можливо, було б ще краще, якби Ви візуально відділили основну тезу (остаточні висновки). І, можливо, ще написали, які саме символи радите використовувати у фонологічному записі (хоча запитання не зовсім однозначне, можливо, воно стосується лише фонетичного запису).

Answer (score 4):

Слід розрізняти фонематичний і фонетичний запис у МФА (див. [«International Phonetic Alphabet: Brackets and transcription delimiters»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Brackets_and_transcription_delimiters) в англійській «Вікіпедії»):

- /…/ — це фонематичний запис. Тобто між скісними рисками пишуть [фонеми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0), а не звуки. Фонема — це, умовно кажучи, така абстракція, що уособлює множину звуків, які носій мови вважає «одним і тим же». Наприклад:

  - літеру *а* ми насправді вимовляємо в різних випадках трішки по-різному, навіть не поміючаючи цього, — для нас це одна фонема; а для носіїв якихось інших мов ці «різні варіанти _а_», можливо, істотно відрізняються (скажеш не те *а* — і може вийти інше слово); для них це різні фонеми;
  - аналогічно літеру *в* ми вимовляємо в різних випадках по-різному (так, ми можемо розрізнити ці вимови, якщо постараємося, але нас вони цікавлять хіба що з погляду «так звучить незвично», а не «так вийде інше слово») — це для нас одна фонема; ;
  - а носії деяких мов не розрізняють *с* і *ш* (точніше, може, різниця в стилі «в таких випадках правильніше казати отак» і є, але слово інше не вийде) — для них це одна фонема; а для нас, очевидно, різні (*синок* і *шинок*);
  - аналогічно носії деяких мов не розрізняють *п* і *ф*; або *р* і *л*;
  - іще один і той же звук у різних мовах може вважатися реалізацією різних фонем; наприклад, можна вимовити такий звук, що для носія однієї мови буде ще *г*, а для іншої — вже *р*.
- […] — це фонетичний запис. Тобто між квадратними дужками пишуть саме звуки. (Хоча є ще нюанс — звуки можна записувати з різною точністю. Наприклад, те, що в одному місці запишуть як [t̪], в іншому можуть записати просто як [t]; або те, що в одному місці запишуть як [ɹ], в іншому можуть записати як [r]. Тобто навіть запис звуків не обов'язково на 100% точний, автори можуть «лінитися» і не прописувати те, що більш-мент очевидно за контекстом.)

Наприклад:
Фонема | Якими звуками може реалізуватися в українській мові
-|-
/ɑ/ | [ɑ], [ɐ]
/ɔ/ | [ɔ], [o]
/u/ | [u], [ʊ]
/m/ | [m], [m̥]
/l/ | [l], [l̥]
/r/ | [r], [r̥]

Так от, всі звуки від *в* зазвичай вважаються однією фонемою — /w/ (хоча я не знаю, наскільки принципово позначати її саме так, можливо, дозволені різні позначення (але в будь-якому разі це буде одна фонема, незалежно від позиції в слові)). А от самі звуки можуть бути різні: [β̞], [ʋ], [w], [u̯], іноді [ʍ] — зокрема [«Ukrainian phonology: Consonants»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_phonology#Consonants) в англійській «Вікіпедії» каже:

> <sub>/w/ — це найчастіше [губно-губний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96) [β̞] перед голосними, але може чергуватися з [губно-зубним](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96) [ʋ] (найчастіше перед /i/), а також може бути справжнім [лабіовелярним](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) [w] перед /ɔ/ чи /u/. Його також вокалізують як [u̯] на початку слова перед приголосним, після голосного перед приголосним чи в кінці слова після голосного. Якщо /w/ трапляється перед глухим приголосним і при цьому не після голосного, також можливе глухе артикулювання до [ʍ].</sub>

Зазначу, що я не спеціаліст, переказав те, як я сам це розумію (теоретично міг написати не зовсім правильно або просто якоїсь маячні).

Comment: Ви, може, й не спеціаліст, але мені дуже сподобалася ваша відповідь. Детально, дотепно, зрозуміло.