# Чи є вимова «в» у ролі у нескладового як «в» діалектною чи неправильною?

Tags: фонетика

У  [праці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2viI7mIvK04) «Українська літературна вимова» Микола Погрібний казав, що *в* після голосних та перед приголосними треба вимовляти як *у* у слові *аудиторія*: Я мау, на мене біг воук, мене ўбили. Це також доводив Микола Наконечний у [статті](https://zbruc.eu/node/41905) на Збручі. Утім, повно українців вимовляють *в* у тих випадках як *в* у слові *ви*: ма*в* і ле*в*, що часто перетворюється на *ф*.

Чи є така вимова наслідком впливу російської за радянського союзу чи діалектною?

Comment: [Dotıćne](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6843/585)

Comment: дотична, але не відповідає на моє запитання.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Утім, повно українців вимовляють в у тих випадках як в у слові ви: мав
> і лев, що часто перетворюється на ф.

Повно вкраїнців також розмовляють московською ("російською") мовою, й роблять так уже кілька десятиліть, а дехто й під 100 років з початку СРСР (а московські міські переселенці в часи Російської Імперії й довше). І майже кожен українець знає московську, чи чув багато московської мови за своє життя. Якшо не від свого оточення, то, принаймні, по телебаченню, радійо. Через це я не думаю, шо з мови будь-якого пересічного вкраїнця можна судити про питомі риси фонетики, фонології. Якшо багато так говоре, то воно не значе, шо так є природньо для вкраїнської мови. Або "було природньо", якшо мислити через зіницю "розвитку" мови (уплив московської мови = розвиток української мови).

Нескладова, губно-губна вимова /в/ після голосної перед наступною приголосною це явище рідне для всіх українських говорів. Непослідовне воно лише, хіба шо на переферії вкраїнського мовного континивма, де є багато впливу з московської, польської, румунської, чи вгорської мов. Для говірок дотичних до білоруських і словацьких це явище лишається послідовне, оскільки також трапляється й у тих двох мовах. Але судити фонетичну систему мови за переферійними говірками неправильно. Нині це явище лишається найпоширенішим на заході країни, але не через те, шо це явище лише рідне для західних говорів (південно-західних та північних, точніше), а тому шо вкраїнська мова загалом лишається найпоширенішою на заході країни, а тому піддається меншому впливу від московської. Хоча таки піддається. За останні кілька років я помітив, шо зростає кількість мовців із заходу, котрі таки оглушують /в/ до ф у кінці слова, чи перед глухою приголосною. Помітив це я навіть у своїй сім'ї, хоч живу на Львівщині. Усе частіше недотримуються також вимови й актори дублювання, журналісти. Також, до прикладу, в сучасному Ужгороді поширений свій суржик, де мішається тамтешня закарпатська говірка (також "карпаторусинська мова"), літературна вкраїнська мова, московська мова, та угорська мова. Хоч місто Ужгород настільки далеке від московських говорів, наскільки це взагалі можливо, ця відстань не зупинила поширення московських слів і виразів у тамтешнє мовлення.

Підсумок:

> Чи є вимова «в» у ролі у нескладового як «в» діалектною чи неправильною?
> ф

Діалектною? Ні. Неправильною? Також ні. Чи є вимова /в/ як [ф] неправильна? Залежить від того, шо ви гадаєте під "правильна" вимова. Якшо "відповідає правилам літературної вимови", то ні, оглушення /в/ до [ф] неправильне. Якшо "відповідає природі вкраїнської вимови та питомим фонетичним рисам українських говірок", то також ні, не відповідає. Якшо ж "відповідає дійсній вимові багатьох українців сьогодні", то... так, відповідає.

Comment: О, Антоне, давно вас не бачив:)